# TypeError Jquery(...).function is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm having an issue with calling a method that has got me completely stumped. I have a set of methods in an external js class that's used for libraries outside core js for the WP theme.

(Sorry About the unending line)

**external.js**

```
(function(a){
    var b=0;a.fn.mobileMenu=function(c){function e(a){return a.is("ul, ol")}function f(){return a(window).width()<d.switchWidth}function g(c){if(c.attr("id")){return a("#mobileMenu_"+c.attr("id")).length>0}else{b++;c.attr("id","mm"+b);return a("#mobileMenu_mm"+b).length>0}}function h(a){if(a.val()!==null){document.location.href=a.val()}}function j(b){b.css("display","none");a("#mobileMenu_"+b.attr("id")).show()}function k(b){b.css("display","");a("#mobileMenu_"+b.attr("id")).hide()}function l(b){if(e(b)){var c='<div class="td_mobile_menu_wrap"><select id="mobileMenu_'+b.attr("id")+'" class="mobileMenu">';c+='<option value="">'+d.topOptionText+"</option>";b.find("li").each(function(){var b="";var e=a(this).parents("ul, ol").length;for(i=1;i<e;i++){b+=d.indentString}var f=a(this).find("a:first-child").attr("href");var g=b+a(this).clone().children("ul, ol").remove().end().text();c+='<option value="'+f+'">'+g+"</option>"});c+="</select></div>";b.parent().append(c);a("#mobileMenu_"+b.attr("id")).change(function(){h(a(this))});j(b)}else{alert("mobileMenu will only work with UL or OL elements!")}}function m(a){if(f()&&!g(a)){l(a)}else if(f()&&g(a)){j(a)}else if(!f()&&g(a)){k(a)}}var d={switchWidth:td_switch_width_normal,topOptionText:"Menu",indentString:"-"};return this.each(function(){if(c){a.extend(d,c)}var b=a(this);a(window).resize(function(){m(b)});m(b)})}})(jQuery);
```

And then the core

**site.js**

```
jQuery('#td-top-menu .sf-menu').mobileMenu();
```

and i end up with the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).mobileMenu is not a function
```

Somewhere along the line, i've managed to break this code and yet i'm not truly sure. I've stripped my header down to just the necessary scripts and nothing causes the error. My current JQuery CDN is the standard downloaded one from google cdn. I was under the impressional that i would get this issue because it cannot resolve the method. But if both scripts are there (I've logged external.js method to see that the script isn't broken), i don't see why it's throwing this error.

The site is http://whatzbuzzing.com to see the error first hand. As a wordpress distribution, i was under the impression that something has gone wrong outside the two files shown because they haven't been edited at all.

Comment: Sounds like you're not loading the files in the correct order. `external.js` must be loaded before `site.js`.

Comment: That's what i thought, and i switched the order up to no avail. In the console, anything in external.js is logged before site.js.

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with the order of requests in Chrome Networks panel, you're loading external.js before jquery.min.js. Maybe you could try to fetch jquery.min.js before fetching of external.js? Sorry if I missed anything in your question.

Comment: There are two different jquery scripts in the header, and one of them loads before the other two scripts (none of the internal scripting is broken before the error)

Answer (score 0):

this happens when multiple jquery files are loaded, not a very uncommon thing in a wordpress site.

in your case the problem is here

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

jquery comes bundled with wordpress, all you have to do is to properly enqueue your script with jquery as a dependency

```
function enqueue_my_external_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'externaljs', '//example.com/path/to/external.js', array( 'jquery') );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_external_script' );
```

if you're calling this from a theme you can use [get_template_directory_uri](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) to get the theme directory's url like this

```
function enqueue_my_external_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'externaljs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/path/to/external.js', array( 'jquery') );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_external_script' );
```

[wp_enqueue_script function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

[wp_enqueue_scripts action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)